# Make sure deserializing objects is safe here - SonarQube error

Tags: security, plugins, sonarqube, shopware

I got the following error (SECURITY_HOTSPOT error) from sonarQube while analyzing my project.

> Make sure deserializing objects is safe here.

```
$objectData = unserialize($objectData, ['allowed_classes' => false]);
```

The function is used only for internal operations. No execution from the browser and the `$objectData` is fetching from the database.

How to fix this error message.

Or simply ignore it?

Comment: How do you ensure that $objectData is used only internally?

Comment: $objectData is fetching from the database.